# mongodb: how to search integer in a text index?

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to create a text index for a mongo collection to be able to do text search.

While the text search works perfectly for searching through the index using text, I am not able to search integer fields I have added in the index.

I am using mongo `v3.0.7`

Following are the steps to replicate the problem:

```
> <!-- added two dummy fields -->;
> db.test.insert({a: 1, b: "apple"});
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
>
> db.test.insert({a: 2});
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
>
>
> <!-- initially only default index exists -->;
> db.test.getIndexes();
[
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "_id" : 1
        },
        "name" : "_id_",
        "ns" : "3dphy_dev.test"
    }
]
>
>
> <!-- created new text index -->;
> db.test.createIndex({"a": "text", "b": "text"});
{
    "createdCollectionAutomatically" : false,
    "numIndexesBefore" : 1,
    "numIndexesAfter" : 2,
    "ok" : 1
}
>
>
> db.test.getIndexes();
[
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "_id" : 1
        },
        "name" : "_id_",
        "ns" : "3dphy_dev.test"
    },
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "_fts" : "text",
            "_ftsx" : 1
        },
        "name" : "a_text_b_text",
        "ns" : "3dphy_dev.test",
        "weights" : {
            "a" : 1,
            "b" : 1
        },
        "default_language" : "english",
        "language_override" : "language",
        "textIndexVersion" : 2
    }
]
>
>
> <!-- searching for text yields result -->;
> db.test.find({$text: {$search: "apple"}});
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56497f6f96621a852197891b"), "a" : 1, "b" : "apple"}
>
>
> <!-- integer search doesn't works -->;
> db.test.find({$text: {$search: "1"}});
> db.test.find({$text: {$search: "2"}});
```

The last two search commands yield no results.

I am trying to build a single api endpoint for my search where I can search both text and integer data in a collection.

Plz advice!

Answer (score -1):

The second search doesn't work because the type of the `$search` is not `String` ( `"1"` or `"2"` in this case ). Have you try this:

```
    db.test.find({a:1});
```

Comment: Yes i know what you suggest would work. But like I said i want to create a single endpoint for both text and numerical search, without having to worry about in which field my query string is actually stored. Or to differentiate between text and numerical query string